# How to stack elements in QGIS according to the order of numeric size

Tags: qgis

I generated a polygon layer using line to polygon conversion。[image]

[image]
But the one with the largest area is at the top, so I cannot select other polygon elements。

> To do this, open the layer properties, head to the Symbology tab, scroll down to the Layer rendering group box on this page, where you find a Control feature rendering order checkbox. Once this is checked, there is a A->Z button on which you can define which attribute(s) should define the sort order and if it should be in descending or ascending order.

I found this method, but it is only a display effect and cannot truly place polygon features with smaller areas on top。

I also tried `Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> UniondifferenceMerge`, but it will divide the polygon into a circular shape

How to place smaller elements on larger ones

Comment: One workaround is to use the Identify Features tool; it will identify multiple overlapping features, so go through clicking on the relevant features in the Identify Results panel until the one you want is highlighted in the canvas. Then right click that feature in the panel and click 'Toggle Feature Selection'. Each time you do this you add to the selection (doesn't reset). Tedious but does work.

Comment: If it is only about visualization, check the *Control feature rendering order* with a corresponding expression, that contains e.g. `$area`. https://www.cadlinecommunity.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/6454191288221-QGIS-How-to-Control-the-Drawing-Order-of-Map-Features

Comment: Do your initial lines and thus your polygons have any property like the altitude they correspond to ? If so you can order the display by that value, otherwise use the answers below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. you can use the `Order by expression` processing tool and use `$area`as expression. But this would result in a new dataset.

[image]

2. you can use a virtual layer with the following definition:

   `select * from polygonlayer order by st_area(geometry) desc`

[image]