# How to change polygons order of appearance in QGIS and keep it when exporting in GeoJSON

Tags: qgis, geojson, overlapping-features

I am trying to change the overlapping order of certain polygons in my layer in QGIS. I applied the function found in Properties>Symbology>Layer rendering and set the order of appearance by two fields: The first one ascending and the second one (a on-purpose field named rendering) descending. This theoretically should give me the possibility of controlling the order of appearance when some polygons are overlapping.

My final purpose is to export the shapefile as a GeoJSON file to be uploaded in OpenLayers. However, when opening the GeoJSON file I see that the polygons still keep the original order of appearance.

Is there any other possibility to solve the situation? Right now I am changing manually the GeoJSON by cut/paste the overlapping polygons in the proper order (the smaller should appear on top of the bigger ones), but it's a quite long process.

Comment: have a look to this thread, which may be covers your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474600/how-to-stack-elements-in-qgis-according-to-the-order-of-numeric-size/474602

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem!